# Animation in Android

Tags: android, animation

I need to use 3D animation in my android application .
I have tried to get help from API demo but i could not solved it .
Is there any solution for how to use custom 3D animation android.
OR is there any good link for that ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the code from APIDemos to start with. What is not working for you?

Comment: I need 3D rotation when swap from one activity to another activity.